# Is there any way to skip the sign-in window once the user has signed in once using Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I am creating a simple text messaging app using Firebase and Android Studio (Java), and I have used Phone number based sign-in in the app. But it is quite irritating to sign in every time I open the app. Is there some way I can skip the sign-in window, and directly go to the MainActivity using some token-based verification after first sign-in, or using some in-built method? (If this question has been answered, I'll be glad to see that.)

Comment: Unless you are logging the user out whenever you shutdown the app, they will remain signed in. Which you should be checking for during the "splash screen" phase of your app. However, during development, you will be constantly deleting and rebuilding your app, along with any cached data, which will invalidate any previous authentication sessions. If you haven't already, configure a phone auth test account (with a fake number!) as these use the same verification code every time.

Comment: Alternatively, create a Callable Cloud Function that swaps a secret token for a custom auth token so you can log in called something like `getDevAuthToken`. The secret should change regularly (at least once a week), you should disable the Cloud Function whenever you aren't actively doing development, and the secret should never be included in production builds or source control. When your app starts up and detects that the secret has been given, it will call the function to exchange the secret for a custom auth token, which can then be used to sign in instead of showing the sign in flow.

Comment: @samthecodingman Awesome, thanks for the answer! The first answer seems more relevant, as second is a bit more complex and will consume some time. Thanks again! I don't know how to close the question, if you can write the comment in form of an answer try to do it, as I think this problem might be faced by others, I'll accept that answer and mark this question as closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched and tested my app a bit, and I found the answer to why was this happening. Every time you rebuild your app, the authentication gets revoked, as your data is cleared. But if you do not rebuild your app, and try to reopen it, it will check if you already have signed-in before (if you have set this up, in my case it was) and if you have set that up, you will directly land up to the `View` that your Login `View` takes you to, without getting to the Login `View` again.